# Java - Remove multiple IFs for null check

Tags: java, dictionary

I get an object and a map in the method, and I need to migrate all object field values to a map. Which will be later saved in the DB. Values of the map cannot be null.
This is the code:

```
public static final EMP_LAST_NAME_ATTR = "firstName";
public static final EMP_FIRST_NAME_ATTR = "lastName";
...ect.
```

and

```
public void addAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes, Employee employee) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(employee.getFirstName())) {
        attributes.put(EMP_FIRST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getFirstName());
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(employee.getLastName())) {
        attributes.put(EMP_LAST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getLastName());
    }
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(employee.getEmail())) {
        attributes.put(EMP_EMAIL_ATTR, employee.getEmail());
    }
    ...etc many more ifs
}
```

Unfortunately it has to be a map, as the DB table is created as key/value, and I can't change the the entities.
 Any way of shortening this IF nightmare?

Comment: what about your design? Maybe it make sense to add such a method to the Employee class.

Comment: Can't modify "Employee" jpa entity, it's in a library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to refactor the if block into its own method:

```
private void putIfNotBlank(Map<String, String> attributes, String key, String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
        attributes.put(key, values);
    }
}
```

and your method beomes easier to read:

```
public void addAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes, Employee employee) {
    putIfNotBlank(attributes, EMP_FIRST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getFirstName());
    putIfNotBlank(attributes, EMP_LAST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getLastName());
    putIfNotBlank(attributes, EMP_EMAIL_ATTR, employee.getEmail());
}
```

Comment: dammit! late by 13 seconds :(

Comment: but yeah, my naming is wayyyy better :D

Answer (score 1):

```
private void addAttribute(Map<String, String> attributes, String key, String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
        attributes.put(key, value);
    }
}


public void addAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes, Employee employee) {
    addAttribute(attributes, EMP_FIRST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getFirstName());
    addAttribute(attributes, EMP_LAST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getLastName());
    addAttribute(attributes, EMP_EMAIL_ATTR, employee.getEmail());


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a method to do it for you.

```
public void addAttributes(Map<String,String> attributes, Employee employee)
{
    addAttribute(attributes, EMP_FIRST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getFirstName());
    addAttribute(attributes, EMP_LAST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getLastName());
    .....
}

private void addAttribute(Map<String,String> attributes, String ATTR_NAME, String value)
{
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) attributes.put(ATTR_NAME, value);
}
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Do some refactoring by creating a utility method that captures the essence of the check:

```
public static void putIfNotBlank(Map<String, String> map, String key, String value) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value))
        map.put(key, value);
}
```

Then call it for each attribute:

```
putIfNotBlank(attributes, EMP_EMAIL_ATTR, employee.getEmail());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jackson Json ObjectMapper library

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,String> map = mapper.convert(mapper.writeValueAsString(<yourObject),new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
```

Comment: Don't want to introduce another dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a new Map that had this behaviour built in:

```
public class NonBlankValueMap extends HashMap<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value))
            return super.put(key, value);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then simply:

```
Map<String, String> attributes = new NonBlankValueMap();
```

And:

```
attributes.put(EMP_FIRST_NAME_ATTR, employee.getFirstName());
```